# SQL query: insert values into polygon where features of the polygon intersects another polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin-4

I'm very new to sql so I apologize in advance for my very dummy question...

I'm looking for a way to insert into a table A some values stored in another table B only for the features of table A that intersects features of table B.

I tried this:

```
insert into schema.table_A(columnKJ1)
select "columnPO4" from schema.table_B
WHERE table_A.geom.STintersects(table_B.geom) = 1
```

but I get this error message: `cross-database references are not implemented`

What is the right way to do that please ?

Comment: TIP: Write it as a stand-alone query first. Once it's returning the records you want to insert, simply put `insert into <tablename>(<columns>)` before the select. Right now your select by itself doesn't work: it's trying to reference a table in your `insert` which isn't allowed. Your query that works stand-alone will of course need to reference `table_A`.

Comment: Also your `STintersects` syntax looks like that for SQL Server which won't work on Postgres!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to reference `table_A` in the `insert` inside the `select`. The query needs to work stand-alone.

The following should work (untested):

```
insert into schema.table_A(columnKJ1)
select "columnPO4"
from schema.table_B
join schema.table_A on st_intersects(table_a.geom, table_B.geom);
```